# Child elements in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, styles

In our application there is a "basic" layout for all views. To reuse common code, I have crated a BaseControl class and a template for it.

What I want to achieve is a common title and a footer bar for every control derived from "BaseControl"

concrete view in XAML:

```
<my:BaseControl x:Class="SampleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UserInterface" d:DesignWidth="924">
<Grid>
    //This elements are not visible - why?
</Grid>
```

Common base class (no XAML but template)

```
public class BaseControl : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl{}
```

Template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:BaseControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Grid>
                ....snip
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Name="SomeCommonUsedBorder">

                <ContentPresenter>
                  //every thing placed between
                  //<SampleView> and </SampleView> should go here
                 </ContentPresenter>

                ....snip
                //some other commonly used elements goes here
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The sample view looks like expected, but every thing I write inside the derived Control is not visible.

Thank you for any hints and ideas

Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some minutes after posting this question I found the answer.
I have to define the TargetType for the ControlTemplate. Otherwise the TargetType is Control. And Control itself does not have a Content property.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
```